# Basemap great circle longitudinal wrapping and missing data issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am attempting to plot multiple great circles using a for loop in conjunction with a set of lat/lon points. I am using the animation function with matplotlib to make the plots update when the data source is updated. This is all working well.

I noticed that plotting greatcircles where the shortest distance is wrapping the image, the plot will use that and appear on the other side of the map. **Is there an argument that prevents this?**

**Also, depending on where the plot is I notice the "middle" of the plot arc is missing. What could be causing this?** Map and code below:

The CSV uses the following points:(Moscow and Tokyo)

```
sourcelon   sourcelat   destlon    destlat
 55.44      37.51      -80.84      35.22
 139        35.6       -80.84      35.22
```

Minimal code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation


# setup mercator map projection.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(27, 20))
m = Basemap(projection='mill', lon_0=0)
m.drawcoastlines(color='r', linewidth=1.0)


def animate(i):

    df = pd.read_csv('c:/python/scripts/test2.csv', sep='\s*,\s*',header=0, encoding='ascii', engine='python'); df 


    for x,y,z,w in zip(df['sourcelon'], df['sourcelat'], df['destlon'], df['destlat']):
        line, = m.drawgreatcircle(x,y,z,w,color='r')



ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [wikipedia tells us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)

> The great-circle distance or orthodromic distance is the shortest distance between two points on the surface of a sphere, measured along the surface of the sphere.

So the path shown goes the shortest distance, which might wrap from one side of the image to the other.

The missing points in the line are a bit of a mystery, but it might be that there is some problem with the projection in use. Using a different projection, this works fine, e.g. `projection='robin'`:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='grey', linewidth=1.0)

a = [[55.44, 37.51, -80.84, 35.22],[139, 35.6, -80.84, 35.22]]
x,y,z,w = a[0]
line, = m.drawgreatcircle(x,y,z,w,color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

The problem can be circumvented if the distance between points in enlarged, e.g.

```
line, = m.drawgreatcircle(x,y,z,w,del_s=1000,color='r')
```

would give

[image]

Another workaround would be to get the data from the line and plot it manually,

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
m = Basemap(projection='mill', lon_0=0)
m.drawcoastlines(color='grey', linewidth=1.0)

a = [[55.44, 37.51, -80.84, 35.22],[139, 35.6, -80.84, 35.22]]
x,y,z,w = a[0]
line, = m.drawgreatcircle(x,y,z,w,color='r')
line.remove()
mx,my = line.get_data()
m.plot(mx,my, color="limegreen")

plt.show()
```

[image]